# Insert an incremented ID column value during import through macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table in DB,

```
ID  Name    role
1   raj     student
2   kumar   student
3   ajay    professor
```

Now I have the below data in excel and need to upload this data through macros.

```
ID  Name    role
    kamal   student
    khan    HOD
```

How should the ID column value be incremented automatically during macros upload ie. it should take the maximum id from db and increment the id by 1 (like below)

```
ID  Name    role
4   kamal   student
5   khan    HOD
```

Comment: Shouldn't the ID be set in the DB itself as incremental?

Answer (score 0):

After importing the data (leaving the ID in column A blank), use a data series to complete the operation.

```
Dim fr As Long, lr As Long
With Sheets("My_Imported_Data")
    fr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(fr, 1), .Cells(lr, 1)).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
End With
```

That assumes that there is a number from previous imports to reference. If there is no number, the top of column A must be seeded with a starting number.